# Iterate over objects in a rspec testcase

Tags: ruby, rspec

In an rspec test I want to implement shared tests for two different classes to avoid a repetition. The tests are performed on the objects `foo` and `bar`. My test has the following structure:

```
let(:foo) { create(:foo) }
let(:bar) { create(:bar) }

FOOBAR = {
  "foo" => foo,
  "bar" => bar
}

describe 'POST :id/foobar_type/:foobar_id/do' do
  FOOBAR.each do |foobar_type, foobar|
    it 'creates something on an foobar' do
    end

    it 'raises an error if unauthorized' do
    end

    ...
  end
end
```

This does not work as expected since `foo` and `bar` are not available during the declaration of `FOOBAR`. They are only valid during an `it` block. How can I implement such a test pattern?

Comment: Have you tried using the shared behaviors functionality in Rspec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at [shared_examples](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples).

For the slightly abstract example you gave:

```
RSpec.shared_examples 'good foobar' do |foobar|
   it 'creates something on a foobar' do
   end

   it 'raises an error if unauthorized' do
   end
   ... 
end
```

You can then call the shared example like this.

```
describe 'POST :id/foobar_type/:foobar_id/do' do
  it behaves_like 'a good foobar' foo
  it behaves_like 'a good foobar' bar
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to make `FOOBAR` a non-constant then you can define it like

```
let(:foobar) { 'foo' => foo, 'bar' => bar }
```

Or, if you want to keep it as a constant (which i don't think you should because it depends on the values of `foo` and `bar` and they are not constant)

```
before do
  FOOBAR = { 'foo' => foo, 'bar' => bar }
end
```